# Flutter C Interop with omp.h on iOS

Tags: c, objective-c, swift, xcode, flutter

I'm trying to make a C interop in Flutter in iOS.
The code uses omp.h and when compilling it in Xcode says `omp.h` not found.
What I've tried:

- Install OpenMP library.
- Change compiler to GCC in Xcode but didnt find any ways to do that.
- Included `omp.h` manually in code folder.

When included omp.h manually it goes, but now I'm getting this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_omp_init_nest_lock", referenced from:
      _count_3_initialize in count_3_initialize.o
  "_omp_destroy_nest_lock", referenced from:
      _count_3_terminate in count_3_terminate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've tried using a dylib but this error appears:

```
Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Failed to lookup symbol (dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, increment): symbol not found)
```

Anyone have experiencied a problem like that before?

Answer (score 0):

Need more information to know what happened exactly. But what I guess is:

1. check your library via `file` command, does it contains x86_64 arch or not.
2. use `__attribute__((used))` to decorate your C function, like:

```
__attribute__((used)) void increment(){
//...
}
```

in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Your installed library could be linked against macOS (e.g. installed by `brew install libomp`), you cannot use the macOS library for iOS or iPhone Simulator to link.

So we need to compile it ourselves:

```
wget https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/download/llvmorg-14.0.6/openmp-14.0.6.src.tar.xz
tar -xf openmp-14.0.6.src.tar.xz
cd openmp-14.0.6.src

mkdir -p build
cmake -B build \
    -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=ios.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=./build/install \
    -DIOS_PLATFORM=OS -DENABLE_BITCODE=1 -DENABLE_ARC=0 -DENABLE_VISIBILITY=0 -DIOS_ARCH="arm64;arm64e" \
    -DPERL_EXECUTABLE=$(which perl) \
    -DLIBOMP_ENABLE_SHARED=OFF -DLIBOMP_OMPT_SUPPORT=OFF -DLIBOMP_USE_HWLOC=OFF
cmake --build build -j 3
cmake --build build --target install
```

The above would create a static library `libomp.a` for iOS, if you want a library for Simulator also, you need to set `-DIOS_PLATFORM=SIMULATOR` and `-DIOS_ARCH="x86_64;arm64"`

Here's my implementation on creating a `OpenMP.xcframework` which can support both iOS and iPhone Simulator: https://github.com/flyinghead/flycast/pull/805/